# Unity: saving Inspector to script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im wondering if its posible to save seralized data from inspector back into script.

if I'm creating a data base class from inspector, could i write it to the file.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Item
{
//attributes
}
```

```
public class ItemDataBase : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Item[] items =
        {
        new Item("Sword",Item.itemType.Weapon,"a sharp blade"),
        new Item("Hammer",Item.itemType.Weapon,"looks heavy"),
        new Item("Spear",Item.itemType.Weapon,"sharp stick"),
        new Item("Health Potion",Item.itemType.Weapon,"color of blood")
    };

}
```

lets say if i would build up this database form inspector, could i wright/update this file

Comment: Have you looked at scriptable objects?

Comment: What file? Unity already **DOES** serialize this to files .. either within your scene, prefab etc assets are all basically YAML serialized data